# Javascript - использование indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

> Задача - у нескольких пользователей могут быть одинаковые друзья, сделай так чтобы возвращаемый массив не содержал повторений.

Подскажите где ошибка?

```
const getFriends = (users) => users.filter(user => user.friends.indexOf(friends));
```

Comment: А `friends` - это что? Если массив, тогда изначально подход неверный. К тому же indexOf возвращает -1, если ничего не найдет. А это число в логическом контексте `true`. В таких случаях нужно сравнивать результат с -1, `indexOf(...) != -1`

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я понимаю, Вам нужно убрать повторы из массива.
Это можно сделать через `Set`

```
const getFriends = (users) => [...new Set(users)];

getFriends([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

В случаи если у Вас массив объектов:

```
const getFriends = (users) => users.filter((item, index)=>users.findIndex(t => (t.name === item.name)) === index);

getFriends({name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Alex'}, {name: 'Mary'}, {name: 'Peter'})
```

Comment: Там массив состоит из объектов. `[...new Set([{a: 1}, {a: 1}, {a: 1}])]` — останутся все три, т.к. каждый объект разный, хоть и содержимое одинаковое.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME согласен, добавил второй вариант, с массивом объектов

Comment: @Crus или `[ ...new Set( users.map(item => item.name) ) ]`;